# MySQL drop unique index

Tags: mysql

How can I drop this unique index on MySQL?
`alter table user add UNIQUE index(name,age);`
I have done this sentence blew.
`DROP UNIQUE INDEX (name,age) ON  user;`
But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use `SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name` to find out the name of the index. The name of the index is stored in the column called `key_name` in the results of that query.

Then you can use `DROP INDEX`:

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON tbl_name
```

or the ALTER TABLE syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP INDEX index_name
```

Your code do not work because of the query:

```
DROP UNIQUE INDEX (name,age) ON  user;  // Here you are using the incorrect name of index
```

Comment: Cannot drop index `cid` : needed in a foreign key constraint.

Comment: cid is the key_name

Comment: Is there a foreign key constraint implemented on this column ?

Comment: After I use  SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name , I got two same  Key_name named cid. Is it simple?

Comment: yes, cid is a foreign key related to anther table's id

Comment: You cannot drop a column when there is a foreign key defined on that column, its just like you are trying to collapse the 1st floor of a building which has 20 floor.

Comment: Should I drop the foreign key first, then drop this index?

Comment: It works.Thank u very much, your answer has been very helpful.